# unix find latest version of file in subdirectories

Tags: file, unix, find, version

i have to find the latest version of a file in subdirectories

```
user1@host1:/tmp/pathtofind> find . -name "*.txt" -printf "%T+ %p\n"
2013-11-21+13:34:05.7255244000 ./20131119/abc.txt
2013-11-21+13:33:56.5965250740 ./20131120/abc.txt
2013-11-21+13:34:17.6735259520 ./20131118/abc.txt
2013-11-21+13:33:53.0055261810 ./20131121/abc.txt
```

All I need is the path and filename of the latest version of the file for further processing, in this case it would be ./20131118/abc.txt

Can you please help me how to do this?

Regards, vishal

**EDIT:**

Sorry what I actually need is the last version of every distinct filename (abc.txt and def.txt) in a directory:

```
user1@host1:/tmp/pathtofind$ find . -name "*.txt" -printf "%T+ %p\n"
2013-11-21+17:56:48.4251785260 ./20131121/abc.txt
2013-11-21+17:56:57.8651782010 ./20131121/def.txt
2013-11-21+17:56:37.6731789030 ./20131118/abc.txt
2013-11-21+17:57:14.2571776330 ./20131118/def.txt
2013-11-21+17:56:24.2011793670 ./20131119/abc.txt
2013-11-21+17:57:24.4011772720 ./20131119/def.txt
2013-11-21+17:56:29.1371791980 ./20131120/abc.txt
2013-11-21+17:57:19.6411774490 ./20131120/def.txt

user1@host1:/tmp/pathtofind$ find . -name "*.txt" -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort | tail -1
2013-11-21+17:57:24.4011772720 ./20131119/def.txt
```

only finds the latest version of a textfile.

what i actually need in this case would be:

```
2013-11-21+17:56:48.4251785260 ./20131121/abc.txt
2013-11-21+17:57:24.4011772720 ./20131119/def.txt
```

regards, vishal

Answer (score 1):

Change the `printf` format to emit the seconds since epoch and sort.  Saying:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort | tail -1
```

would print the newest file.

```
   -printf format
          ...
                 @      seconds  since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT, with frac‐
                        tional part.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my scenario was incomplete, see edit. regards, vishal

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the above output to

```
sort -k1.43 -k1r|uniq -s42
```

- this sorts by filename (which starts at column 43) and then reverse by timestamp (so that the latest version comes first) and prints the first occurrence of each filename.